# Tentative of shh->rsync to wrong IP; potential security risk?

Tags: ssh, rsync, ssh-keys, ip-address, raspbian

I have set up a little RPI backup 'server' (with rpi OS) on my LAN. I use it to create a backup of my main personal machine data using `rsync`, and I reach it from outside my network through SSH (key-based authentification; I have disabled all the other authentification modes). My domain name provider has a DNS service that I use to assign an URL to my current IP; this IP is not fixed and I thus use `ddclient` to update it when required.

However at some point the update has not been made and my dedicated script tried to SSH to an IP that was not assigned by my ISP to my network anymore (and I guess has been assigned to someone else). What kind of information has been transmitted to this 'someone else' when I tried to SSH to the wrong IP? Are there any security risks?

Comment: You have nothing to worry about. The mechanics of key exchange ensure that the process is terminated if the other side (server or client) isn’t trusted. So, even if the incorrect IP was listening for SSH connections (unlikely) then you still haven’t divulged anything of substance to the server. Look up “SSH key exchange” if you want to know more of the details.

Comment: thx a lot for your answer @JG7 ! Maybe you can 'convert' your comment to an answer in order for me to accept it?